# Mongoose post middleware triggers deleteMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose collections (User and Property). A user can have multiple properties and multiple users can have the same property.
On deletion of a User, I would like to delete his referenced properties (only the ones that are not referenced by another user).

These are the two collections

model/User.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: { type: String, default: null },
  last_name: { type: String, default: null },
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: { type: String },
  token: { type: String },
  properties: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'property' }]
});

userSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', function(doc) {
  Property.deleteMany({_id: { $in: doc.properties }});
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

model/Property.js

```
const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
   },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['house', 'apartment', 'room' ,'parking', 'pool']
  },
  numberOfBedrooms: { type: Number },
  numberOfBathrooms: { type: Number },
  maxNumberOfGuests: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("property", propertySchema);
```

On my User controller, when I try to use findOneAndDelete it activates the post for "findOneAndDelete" but does not perform the deletion of the referenced properties. Do you know why ?
And do you have any idea about how to delete just the properties that are not referenced anywhere else ?

Thank you a lot !
Louie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `await Property.deleteMany({_id: { $in: doc.properties }})`. `Property.deleteMany()` returns a [thenable](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/thenable), which needs to be called with `await` or `.then()`, unlike a regular promise. I believe you can also use `.exec()` in Mongoose.

Comment: Thank you Liz, it works perfectly. Do you have any idea about how I could delete only the Properties that are not referenced by another User ? Thank you again !

Comment: I'm not really sure how you'd do that without making some changes to your schemas or creating unscalable queries. Maybe you could add a boolean property like `referencedMultipleTimes` to your Property schema that you update whenever a property is added to a user. I'm relatively green so hopefully someone with more experience will step in and give you a good answer.